# How to find and print a dictionary key/value that matches user input?

Tags: dictionary, input, key-value, python-3.8

I need to print a dictionary value that matches the input of the user. For example, if the user enters the course number `CS101` the output will look like:

```
The details for CS101 are:
Room: 3004
Instructor: Haynes
Time: 8:00 a.m.
```

However, if the user enters an incorrect/invalid course number, I need to print out a message letting them know:

```
CS101 is an invalid course number.
```

I have tried `if`, `for loops`, and `while loops`. The problem is, every time I get the course info printed, the invalid course number message won't display because of KeyError. On the other hand, if I happen to "fix" the error message, then the course number info won't print out and instead will return a NameError / TypeError.
I will be honest, I have struggled for some time now with this, and I feel as though I am either assigning something incorrectly or printing incorrectly. But I am a beginner and I don't have a great grasp on Python yet, which is why I am asking for help.
Unfortunately, I am not allowed to create one entire dictionary to group everything in (which would have been easier for me), but instead, I have to create 3 dictionaries.
This is the code:

```
room = {}

room["CS101"] = "3004"
room["CS102"] = "4501"
room["CS103"] = "6755"
room["NT110"] = "1244"
room["CM241"] = "1411"

instructor = {}

instructor["CS101"] = "Haynes"
instructor["CS102"] = "Alvarado"
instructor["CS103"] = "Rich"
instructor["NT110"] = "Burkes"
instructor["CM241"] = "Lee"

time = {}

time["CS101"] = "8:00 a.m."
time["CS102"] = "9:00 a.m."
time["CS103"] = "10:00 a.m."
time["NT110"] = "11:00 a.m."
time["CM241"] = "1:00 p.m."

def info():
    print(f'College Course Locater Program')
    print(f'Enter a course number below to get information')

info()
get_course = input(f'Enter course number here: ')
print(f'----------------------------------------------')

course_num = get_course
number = course_num
name = course_num
meeting = course_num

if number in room:
    if name in instructor:
        if meeting in time:
            print(f'The details for course {get_course} are: ')
            print(f'Room: {number["room"]}')
            print(f'Instructor: {name["instructor"]}')
            print(f'Time: {meeting["time"]}')
else:
    print(f'{course_num} is an invalid course number.')
```

I have also tried formatting dictionaries in this style:

```
time_dict = {
    "CS101": {
        "Time": "8:00 a.m."
    },
    "CS102": {
        "Time": "9:00 a.m."
    },
    "CS103": {
        "Time": "10:00 a.m."
    },
    "NT110": {
        "Time": "11:00 a.m."
    },
    "CM241": {
        "Time": "1:00 p.m."
    },
}
```

I thank everyone in advance who has an advice, answer, or suggestions to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code here is unnecessary, because you are essentially setting 4 variables all to the same value get_course:

```
course_num = get_course
number = course_num
name = course_num
meeting = course_num
```

This code here doesn't work because you are trying to find a key with string "room" in a dictionary that doesn't exist, and same with the other lines afterwards

```
print(f'Room: {number["room"]}')
print(f'Instructor: {name["instructor"]}')
print(f'Time: {meeting["time"]}')
```

I replaced the code above with this:

```
print(f'Room: {room[get_course]}')
print(f'Instructor: {instructor[get_course]}')
print(f'Time: {time[get_course]}')
```

This searches the dictionary variable room for the key get_course (ex. "CS101") and returns the value corresponding to that key. The same thing happens for the other lines, except with the dictionary instructor and the dictionary time.

Here is the final code:

```
room = {}

room["CS101"] = "3004"
room["CS102"] = "4501"
room["CS103"] = "6755"
room["NT110"] = "1244"
room["CM241"] = "1411"

instructor = {}

instructor["CS101"] = "Haynes"
instructor["CS102"] = "Alvarado"
instructor["CS103"] = "Rich"
instructor["NT110"] = "Burkes"
instructor["CM241"] = "Lee"

time = {}

time["CS101"] = "8:00 a.m."
time["CS102"] = "9:00 a.m."
time["CS103"] = "10:00 a.m."
time["NT110"] = "11:00 a.m."
time["CM241"] = "1:00 p.m."

def info():
    print(f'College Course Locater Program')
    print(f'Enter a course number below to get information')

info()
get_course = input(f'Enter course number here: ')
print(f'----------------------------------------------')


if get_course in room and get_course in instructor and get_course in time:
    print(f'The details for course {get_course} are: ')
    print(f'Room: {room[get_course]}')
    print(f'Instructor: {instructor[get_course]}')
    print(f'Time: {time[get_course]}')
else:
    print(f'{get_course} is an invalid course number.')
```

Here is a test with the input "CS101":

```
College Course Locater Program
Enter a course number below to get information
Enter course number here: CS101
----------------------------------------------
The details for course CS101 are:
Room: 3004
Instructor: Haynes
Time: 8:00 a.m.
```

Comment: You made it look so easy, I can't believe what a simple fix that was... I think I need to spend some extra time practicing dictionaries for sure. This actually really worked, I am both impressed and grateful and hope to be able to create similar scripts in the future without so much trouble with dictionaries. I will for sure be spending the rest of the evening studying this code for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks! It's all about practice, and you will get better. There is a great video by CS Dojo that helped me understand dictionaries, and I recommend you check it out [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEZdys-fHDw)

Comment: I will definitely check out the video, I really want to get better at working with dictionaries and understanding them. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this. it'll probably take less time. The function is not very organize, try to organize it a little and it should work. I'm still not very familiar with adding codes on here.

```
course_info = {
'CS101': {
    'Room': '3004',
    'Instructor': 'Haynes',
    'Time': '8:00 am'
},
'CS102': {
    'Room': '4501',
   'Instructor': 'Alvarado',
   'Time': '9:00 a.m.'
},
'CS103': {
    'Room': '6755',
    'instructor': 'Rich',
    'Time:': '10:00 am',
},
'NT110': {
    'Room': '1244',
    'instructor': 'Burkes',
    'Time': '11:00 am'
},
'CM241': {
    'Room': '1411',
    'Instructor': 'Lee',
    'Time': '1:00 pm'
},
```

}

```
get_course = input(f'Enter a course number: ')

try:
   courses = course_info[get_course]
   print(f'The details for for course {get_course} are: ')
   print(f"Room: {courses['Room']}, Time: {courses['Time']}, 
                   Instructor: {courses['Instructor']}")
except KeyError:
   print(f'Details not found for {get_course}')
```